# Given the characteristic equation of an operator T, is T invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that the characteristic polynomial of an operator on $\mathbb{C}^5$ is $p(z)=z(z-3)^2(z-2)^2.$ Is the operator invertible?

Attempt: The characteristic equation implies that zero is an eigenvalue for the operator T. Hence, $T(v)=0(v)$, which implies that $T=0$. But the zero map is not injective and so it cannot be invertible.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. It does *not* imply that $T$ is identically zero; however, there does exist a non-zero vector $v$ for which

$$Tv = 0v = 0$$

Hence $Tv = T0$ while $v \ne 0$, so $T$ fails to be injective.

Comment: Thank you for including the fact that there must exists a non-zero vector. Kudos.